# 2 column dataframe stacked data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame that looks like this:

```
+------+------------+
|  A   |     B      |
+------+------------+
| ID   | 1          |
| Date | 2019-04-04 |
| Name | Carl       |
| ID   | 2          |
| Date | 2019-04-05 |
| Name | Jane       |
+------+------------+
```

I'm trying to make an output that looks like this:

```
+----+------------+------+
| ID |    Date    | Name |
+----+------------+------+
|  1 | 2019-04-04 | Carl |
|  2 | 2019-04-05 | Jane |
+----+------------+------+
```

I've tried transpose, pivot, and unstack methods but am really stuck.

Answer (score 4):

Using `cumcount` create the key then `pivot`

```
df['C']=df.groupby('A').cumcount()
df.pivot(index='C',columns='A',values='B')
Out[118]: 
A        Date ID  Name
C                     
0  2019-04-04  1  Carl
1  2019-04-05  2  Jane
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = df.set_index([df.groupby('A').cumcount(), 'A'])['B'].unstack()
print (df)
A        Date ID  Name
0  2019-04-04  1  Carl
1  2019-04-05  2  Jane
```

If order of columns is important add :

```
df = (df.set_index([df.groupby('A').cumcount(), 'A'])['B']
        .unstack()
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
        .reindex(['ID','Date','Name'], axis=1))
print (df)
  ID        Date  Name
0  1  2019-04-04  Carl
1  2  2019-04-05  Jane
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly and I'm going to read up more on set_index.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a dictionary to gather elements then use the `DataFrame` constructor.

```
d = {}

for a, b in zip(df.A, df.B):
    d.setdefault(a, []).append(b)

pd.DataFrame(d)

  ID        Date  Name
0  1  2019-04-04  Carl
1  2  2019-04-05  Jane
```

---

You can also use the `defaultdict` from the `collections` library

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for a, b in zip(df.A, df.B):
    d[a].append(b)

pd.DataFrame(d)

  ID        Date  Name
0  1  2019-04-04  Carl
1  2  2019-04-05  Jane
```